# jenkins build profiling

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, profiling

The builds in my project have started to take more time recently. I need to optimize them, but I don't want to do blind optimizations. I need how many time is consumed by respective steps of the build process (fetching, preparing, build script, publishing etc). It there any jenkins plugin that enables cuch profiling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a profiling tool, but you should start with the Timestamp plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper

This will put a timestamp for every line in your console log. You can then easily see how much time was spent on each particular section (checkout, building, publishing) in the log

Answer (score 1):

If your build calls out to standard build tools like Ant, Maven etc., you may want to give YouMonitor a try: https://www.yourkit.com/youmonitor/features/. Be aware this does not show you any details of the Jenkins pipeline or job, but summarizes the external build tools quite nicely by their goals/targets etc.